# How to set bucket policy to allow access for a particular referrer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, web-scraping, policy, bucket

Our website is currently being scraped by bots to acccess content on S3. I'm trying to get a bucket policy setup so that a S3 URL cannot be accessed by any other referrer except our domain. Problem is that it doesn't seem to detect that our domain is the referrer. Here is the bucket policy we have setup below.

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowPublicRead",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::example/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotLike": {
                    "aws:Referer": [
                        "https://www.example.com/*",
                        "http://www.example.com/*",
                        "https://*.example.com/*",
                        "https://*.example.com/*"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Does anyone know why it wouldn't recognize www.example.com/blah/blah.html etc. as the referrer?

Is there a way to see see what AWS is registering as the referrer when I access a URL via our app? That would help with troubleshooting.

Answer (score 3):

From [Bucket Policy Examples - Restricting Access to a Specific HTTP Referrer](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html#example-bucket-policies-use-case-4):

```
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Id":"http referer policy example",
  "Statement":[
    {
      "Sid":"Allow get requests originating from www.example.com and example.com.",
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal":"*",
      "Action":"s3:GetObject",
      "Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/*",
      "Condition":{
        "StringLike":{"aws:Referer":["http://www.example.com/*","http://example.com/*"]}
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

This policy is Allowing access if the `Referer` string is like those shown in the list.

Your cost is using `StringNotLike`, so it is only permitting access if the Referer is *not* one that you listed.

Comment: Thanks John. I think that was a change I made while experimenting since even with your update it's not working. Is there a way to detect what the bucket is seeing as the referrer, perhaps through the logs?

Comment: I'm not aware of a way to view that information. There is, however, a [Policy Simulator](https://policysim.aws.amazon.com/home/index.jsp?#) that you can use.